# To show data in Django admin page which user send

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-admin

**Question**: How to show data in Django admin page which user send by forms\fields from webpage?!

P.S. I am just beginner in Django so I think my question has easy solution but right now I dont know how to make it. Don`t judge me harshly please. I will be happy for any example or article about it. =)

**forms.py**

```
class TicketForms(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    department = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=True)
    room = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True)
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Ticket(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    department = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    room = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)  # TextField cause room can be 408A as example
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2.7
        return self.name
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Ticket


# Register your models here.
class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket


admin.site.register(Ticket, Admin)
```

Comment: Did you already configured Django admin interface?

Comment: You could create a Ticket model that stores the user's input in the database and save the input during the form submission. Then add an admin model in admin.py for the app.

Comment: Hello @DhiaTN right know my Admin page is empty. I mean I have standart admin page. I am tring to understand how it all works. I am not sure but for my thinking I need to save date to DataBase (sqlite in my case) first right?! Them take that date from DB and show it in admin page. Can you give me some advice?! =)

Comment: Hello @mrkre Thank  you for your answer. Well you know I think it will be better to explane it with some examples. As I understand I need to save data to DB  and then work with models, right?! =)

Comment: You should probably read through the documentation over at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/ to understand how models work. Models act as a representation of your underlying data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have empty admin page, this means you did not registered your models yet in the admin interface. Simply go to app each in the same directory as **models.py** you should find **admin.py** and if not just create it and add the following:

1.
**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ticket.models import Ticket

admin.site.register(Ticket)
```

2.then add your app to **settings.py**:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        ...
        'tickets',
    )
```

3.apply migrations

```
  python manage.py makemigrations
  python manage.py migrate
```

4. Now that you model is ready in **views.py**:

   ```
   def home(request):
       form = TicketForms(request.POST)
       # validate your form
       if form.is_valid():
          Ticket.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
          # return success url
       else:
          context = {'form': form}
          render(request, 'ticket.html', context)
   ```

Check you admin again and you will find the saved data displayed.

And since you are new to Django I will recommend you to go through this official [django tutoriel](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/) with 7 parts.

Comment: Can you check my post again. I updated it with new code. Unfortunately, I dont see ticket application in admin page and the main question is still open.

Comment: Can you share image how your admin interface looks like? Is every else like form submissions working fine? did you apply the database migrations?
In fact I need more details because the code looks okay.

Comment: Great That you shared the picture. Did you add the app to your settings ´INSTALLED_APPS´ and applied migrations ??

Comment: I added image (admin page and structure of the project) to my post. I hope you understand what i want to ask. =)

Comment: You are right I forger to add app to setting files, Sorry for this stupid mistake.

Comment: But anyway how can I see that date which I user wrote in forms. I have such form in webpage as you can see in my post. The main question of post was that. User send message and I want to see that messages in admin page in ticker app. Sorry for my bad English.